# .NET Project Platform

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight

I am a sole developer (experienced in web development) in the company (a newly established one). I received a project to develop an ERP system from ground-up. Naturally, my platform of choice would be ASP.NET. I started the project, fully written in MVC but as I progress further, I find that it is getting increasingly hard to manage.

Despite having a good architecture, Repository, DI, MVC-VM, the system itself is hard to maintain. The stateless nature of HTTP requires me to write a lot of javascript / jQuery to plug holes such as maintaining state, which consumed a lot of my time. Also, since it's a fairly large application, design can sometimes be restrictive which I ended up using javascript to resolve. Think about having a form within a form. This is the kind of problem I've been facing.

Then, I came across Silverlight LOB applications while browsing and wow, I was impressed. Very impressed with the UI and fluidity. So now, I need an advice. Should I take on Silverlight? Or should I stay with MVC? Can Silverlight reduce development time significantly? What is the learning curve like?

Edit: I forgot to mention that this application is strictly for internal staffs only. The only component that interacts with the outside world is the catalog and CMS component.

Answer (score 1):

One year ago we/I faced a similar decision: we had to port our desktop LOB (similar in complexity to an ERP) to the web. We looked at our possible options: Silverlight, Flash (Air) and HTML 5 (javascript).

Since we all had a .net background with little experience in web development we chose Silverlight.
9 months after we switched to HTML 5 :).
What happened:

- both SL and HTML 5 are capable of getting the job done
- if you have a .net (win forms, wpf) background the SL learning curve is smaller.
- the learning curve from desktop to web is high - so no matter what you choose you will have headaches
- SL is also stateless (or better - the SL enabled WCF services we used were session-less) so we had to code the whole state management logic ourselves (not that hard actually)
- managing the complexity of a large project is rather hard also in Silverlight - we used Prism, MEF and a couple of other libraries to better organize the code and get the job done but the project was just large - couple that with some "not so fortunate" decisions (consequence of the lack of web development skills) made navigating within the project a problem
- (good) SL developers are hard to come by - we looked for 6 months and couldn't find anyone to help us with the architecture/design. In this regard it is easier to find (good) ASP.net developers - this is something to consider when thinking about increasing the team or maintenance
- connected to the previous point - the main reason of why we switched from SL to HTML 5 was management pressure - HTML 5 is the buzz word today while SL is seen as a "rather dead" technology (I don't want to get into discussions about this statement - it just depicts how management sees things). When you'll tell them that you want to develop in SL they will ask you "why go SL, when everyone else is going HTML 5"? - it's hard to find good reasons...
- I've also seen nice LoB apps in SL - the 9 months we've put in also led to a rather nice application - but by switching to MVC 4 we could get more people on the project and I have to confess that the MVC app looks just as nice as the SL one. Sure it took some time to get accustomed to javascript (and all its libraries) but I as an ex winforms/wpf/SL developer I've came to appreciate its beauty.
- a note: with some js libraries (knockout, maybe even others) you get the awesome "binding" feature you have in SL (I think XAML and ExpressionBlend were the best things in SL)

Summing up:

- if you already have started with ASP.net MVC my advice is to stick with it - it will be easier with the maintenance/getting people convinced you are in the right tech boat. You can quantify the costs of switching right now to SL (2-3 months to get used to SL and various SL libraries - PRISM, MVVM light, etc. + a couple of months of development to get to the same place you are right now) and with this money you can get another pair of hands to help you with your MVC app.
- if you want slickness/responsiveness get some js libraries - [Kendo](http://www.kendoui.com/) (from telerik) is very nice - looks great and moves fast

  Hope this helps you - if you have any other questions - leave a comment.

Comment: Great reply, much thanks. However, sometimes when dealing with MVC, I'd get stuck with problems like an editable grid (which renders a form) within a main form, end up having to use workaround like Ajax to deal with the problem. On top of that, coding in JS is very time consuming which was what triggered me to source around for other alternatives. Of course, I believe SL has its fair share of troubles too, which is why I need to hear more opinion from people who have experienced both platforms.